# Run once when AngularJS controller loads

Tags: angularjs

I have some stuff that needs to be done only once when the controller is loaded. What's the best way to this? I've read some about the "run block" but I don't really understand how it works.

Some pseudo code:

```
when /app
resolove some stuff
load a view
controllerA

ControllerA:

Some-magic-piece-of-code-only-run-once{
 }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The code you put in the controller is run only once when the controller is loaded. What exactly do you mean? What have you tried? Post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it normally, controllers are just functions injected with $scope, services. When the controller is loaded, this function is called only **once**. You can do anything inside it.

```
app.controller("yourController",function($scope, myService){
   //Write your logic here.


   //Initialize your scope as normal
});
```

Comment: Ah. That was easy. Sometimes you make things more complicated then they are. Thx!

Comment: As @meilke suggested ng-init is best practice.

Comment: @Satyajitsinh Raijada: I don't think so, so does angular official page: `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: @Khanh TO: I read this document long back when Angular 1.0.8 was released. But never thought this way. Thanks.

Comment: Controllers can actually be executed multiple times. For example always when ui-router state changes.

Comment: @Petr Peller: 1 controller instance is actually run once because it's just a function. The case you pointed out is because the controller is recreated with `another instance` everytime state changes.

Comment: @Petr Peller: This is really by design and depends on your application. The point is to run some code `once` to `initialize` your controller. With the case you pointed out, it should not be a problem because the controller is recreated with another instance and this code should be run to initialize this new instance.

Comment: @Petr Peller: It could cause problems when you update your `shared state`( services, attaching event handlers to a global object,...) in your controller, in these cases, you have to handle the scope's $destroy event to cleanup. But if your code is to `initialize` your controller, I believe this is the right way to do.

Comment: @Petr Peller: Did I answer your concerns? I'm glad to discuss further with you.

Comment: I see. In that use-case you are right. What I needed was to run something when the controller is initialised for the first time.

Comment: @Petr Peller: Can you tell me what is your case? It looks to me there is something wrong in the application design. If your code is to initialize the controller, it should be rerun whenever the controller is reinitialized, otherwise, the first instance behaves differently than the second instance. If your controller initialization code modifies some global state, you should be consider whether it's the right place to implement your code.

Answer (score 14):

I always use [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for this.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="init()"/>
```

JS:

```
$scope.init = function () {
  // do something
};
```

The code specified in your controller function is run only once, too:

```
var AppController = function($scope) {
  // do something very early

  $scope.init = function () {
    // do something on loaded
  };

};
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. ng-init is called once no matter how many times the directive gets re-rendered

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response. If you want some functionality to run only once (on application load time) and it depends on some functionality in controller then you'll need to put that functionality in a service/factory and you'll inject that service in the run block (associated to that service) which will be executed just after the service is loaded. If you won't inject service in run block then run block will be executed first independent of your service. So this is what will serve your purpose:

```
angular.module('myangularapp')
.factory('myLogger', ['$http', 'apiUrl',
function ($http, apiUrl) {
    'use strict';
    function PostService() {
        $http({
            url: apiUrl + 'TestEndPoint',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'post',
            data: //some object
        }).then(function success(response) {
        }, function errorCallback(errorThrown) {
        });
    }

    return {
        PostService: PostService
    }
}])
.run(function (myLogger, $rootScope) {
myLogger.PostService();
});
```