# AngularJS controller is executed every time the view is routed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Every time I change the path through a link like the following

```
<li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
```

The controller for the view in the router definition gets run again.

```
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        // $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        $routeProvider.when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/test', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/test.html',
            controller: 'testCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }
]);
```

I don't think that this is default behavior (I found no mention of it in the documentation), however I can't see what the problem is.

P.S.

I don't have an ng-controller assigned to any DOM element in my templates since I've seen someone else with a similar issue where this was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a default behavior.
Basically controller is function used to argument Angular Scope. So it need to be called each time the page associated with the controller is opened. Each time your page is navigated angular will create new scope.

Comment: I had thought it might be (which is why I mentioned it), but then I saw this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401822/run-once-when-controller-loads-angular) which made me think otherwise.

Comment: Yes, he is also saying the same thing. "When the controller is loaded, this function is called only once." but when the controller is loaded and it will load each time associated page is opened up. :)