# AngularJS: How to prevent the angular controller to be loaded every time partial page routed

Tags: angularjs

I have three partial pages in my application and I am using ng-View directive to route to the pages. Also I have separate controller for pages. Now in two of the pages I am making http calls to get / post data, where I am using service to call REST APIs.

Now the problem I am facing every time I am routed to a page, it gets loaded again (executing the function which is making http calls).

In a post like this I saw it is said that this is a default behavior but if so, how can I prevent this to happen. The link I saw is: 
[The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298766/angularjs-controller-is-executed-every-time-the-view-is-routed)

Now how can I prevent that to happen, I really do not need to load pages after it is loaded for the first time, when routed.

The code snippets are as follows..

In index.html 
    To call page link:

```
...
<md-button class="md-primary" ng-href="#/">Report</md-button>
<md-button class="md-primary" ng-href="#about">About</md-button>
...
<div ng-view></div>
....
```

In partial1.html, I am not assigning any controller.

In App.js file, setting the route config...

```
angular
.module('webApp')
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        //url: "/report",
        templateUrl: 'pages/report.html',
        controller: 'ReportController'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutController'
    })
    .....
```

In controller ....

```
angular
.module('webApp')
.controller('ReportController',
function ($scope, $log, $mdDialog, webAppService) {

var GetReportsFromDB = function () {
    webAppService.GetReports().success(function (rptData) {
    var dd = JSON.parse(rptData);
    rptvm.reports = dd;

    }).error(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    }).then(function () {
    });
    };
    GetReportsFromDB();

    ...
```

In Service ...

```
    angular
    .module('webApp')
    .service('webAppService', ['$http', function ($http) {

        var svc = {};

        svc.GetReports = function () {
            console.log('loading...');
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://somedomain/api/mycontroller/myaction',
            });
        };
        ......
```

I am very new at AngularJS. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Arpan

Comment: You could choose not to execute the `GetReportsFromDB` method in the `ReportsController` controller. That way, you won't be making any unwanted HTTP requests.

Comment: Maybe you want to add some caching for your requests : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching

Comment: Not executing from reports controller, may not solve my purpose. As I have HTTP calls in other controllers as well

Comment: For caching, I can use it, but just want to know if there are some way to stop loading it again and again. If I use ui-router view , will it solve the issue? Or it is the same behavior for this as well